# Using R to create and merge zoo object time series from csv files

Tags: r, csv, merge, zoo

I have a large set of csv files in a single directory. These files contain two columns, `Date` and `Price`. The `filename` of `filename.csv` contains the unique identifier of the data series. I understand that missing values for merged data series can be handled when these times series data are zoo objects. I also understand that, in using the `na.locf(merge() function`, I can fill in the missing values with the most recent observations.

I want to automate the process of.

1. loading the `*.csv` file columnar Date and Price data into R dataframes.
2. establishing each distinct time series within the Merged zoo "portfolio of time series" objects with an identity that is equal to each of their s.
3. merging these zoo objects time series using `MergedData <- na.locf(merge( ))`.

The ultimate goal, of course, is to use the `fPortfolio` package.

I've used the following statement to create a data frame of `Date,Price` pairs. The problem with this approach is that I lose the `<filename>` identifier of the time series data from the files.

```
  result <- lapply(files, function(x) x <- read.csv(x) )
```

I understand that I can write code to generate the R statements required to do all these steps instance by instance. I'm wondering if there is some approach that wouldn't require me to do that. It's hard for me to believe that others haven't wanted to perform this same task.

Comment: "The problem with this approach is that I lose the identifier of the data from the files" can you explain this? otherwise write your script in a source e. myprocess.R and you can call it using **Rscript** myprocess.R

Comment: What I mean is this... The csv filenames are not random but provide the identity of the data (e.g., IBM.csv would mean IBM daily returns, etc.). In using that lapply() function above, I lose the names of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have better formatting using `sapply`( keep the files names). Here I will keep `lapply`.

1. Assuming that all your files are in the same directory you can use `list.files`. 
    it is very handy for such workflow.
2. I would use `read.zoo` to get directly zoo objects(avoid later coercing)

For example:

```
zoo.objs <- lapply(list.files(path=MY_FILES_DIRECTORY,
                              pattern='^zoo_*.csv',    ## I look for csv files, 
                                                       ##   which names start with zoo_
                              full.names=T),           ## to get full names path+filename
                   read.zoo)
```

I use now `list.files` again to rename my result

```
 names(zoo.objs) <- list.files(path=MY_FILES_DIRECTORY,
                          pattern='^zoo_*.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks. I did end up using list.files and then lapply along with my own R script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
z <- read.zoo(files, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
z <- na.locf(z)
```

I have assumed a header line and lines like `2000-01-31,23.40` .  Use whatever `read.zoo` arguments are necessary to accommodate whatever format you have.